# как настроить самоподписанный сертификат ssl в локальной сети?

Tags: javascript, ssl, openssl, nestjs

как настроить самоподписанный сертификат ssl так, чтобы две машины внутри локальной сети могли общаться между собой.(тестируем апи и для считывания куки нужен ssl)

**openssl.cnf**:

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
organizationName = text
organizationalUnitName = text
localityName = text
stateOrProvinceName  = text
countryName = Ru
commonName = localhost
emailAddress = example@mail.ru

[v3_req]
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *
IP.1 = 192.168.1.63
IP.2 = 192.168.1.69
```

создаю сертификат и ключ:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private-key.pem -out certificate.pem -days 365 -config openssl.cnf
```

после того, как устанавливается на вторую машину этот сертификат и делается доверенным, вылезают ошибка "net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID".

Comment: Я что-то сомневаюсь что хоть где-то домен `*` будет считаться валидным. Напишите туда что-нибудь более адекватное типа `api.example.org` или `*.example.org`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
commonName = localhost
```

но запрос явно не на localhost.

Используйте easy-rsa для выпуска сертификатов. создайте в нем корневой самоподписный.